# debugging JavaScript with Webpack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack

When I open the console in chrome, the object is displayed. But why can't I access it?

ERROR:
Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
at :1:1

main.js

```
import { Canvas } from "./models/canvas.class.js";

const cvs = document.getElementById('cvs');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

let canvas = new Canvas(ctx);

function loop() {
    canvas.getLog();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();
```

canvas.class.js

```
export class Canvas {

    ctx;

    constructor(ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx; 
    }

    getLog() {
        console.log(this);
    }

}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in short, your code works as intended; but you lack development-testing access from the console? That's a webpack feature - it isolates each module, so nothing lands on global scope.

If you mean dev-time access only, the easiest thing would be exposing the thing you want to access manually:

```
let canvas = new Canvas(ctx);
window.canvas = canvas;
```

then you should be able to interact with it from console.

Alternativelly you can put some break point in your code, and access it in debbuger.